# Translating json to string variable

Tags: java, json, web-services

I'm working on developping a webservice that communicate two application with each other, the first application will send a json object to the second one.
I'm stuck in translating this json object :

```
$body = "{"fields":{"project":{"key":"'+$projectKey+'"}
,"issuetype":{"name": "'+$issueType+'"}
,"summary":"'+$summary+'"
,"description":"'+$description+'"
,"customfield_12721":"'+$FirstName+'"
,"customfield_12722":"'+$LastName+'"
,"customfield_12723":{"value":"'+$EmployeeCategory+'"}
,"customfield_12732":"'+$Externalfunction+'"
,"customfield_12725":"'+$CorporateID+'"
,"customfield_12726":{"value":"'+$VermegCompany+'"}
,"customfield_12685":{"value":"'+$IndusRegion+'"}
,"customfield_12673":{"value":"'+$Product+'"}
,"customfield_12727":{"value":"'+$Profile+'"}
,"customfield_12667":{"name":"'+$Manager+'"}
,"customfield_12708":"'+$BeginDate+'"
,"customfield_14000":"'+$Reglementation+'"
,"customfield_14001":"'+$Department+'"
,"customfield_14002":"'+$SubDepartment+'"} 

}";
```

To a String variable like :

```
String json = "{fields:{project:{\"key\":\""+ projectkey +"}"       
         + "\",\"issuetype\":\"" 
         + "\",\"customfield_12721\":\"" + employee.getFirstName()
         + "\",\"description\":\"" + description
         + "\",\"summary\":\"" + summary    
         + "\",\"customfield_12722\":\""+ employee.getLastName()
         + "\",\"customfield_12732\":\"" + employee.getFte()
         + "\",\"customfield_14000\":\"" + employee.getReglementation()
         + "\",\"customfield_14001\":\"" + employee.getDepartment()
         + "\",\"customfield_14002\":\"" + employee.getSubdepartment()
         + "\",\"fulltime\":" + Math.round(Double.parseDouble(employee.getFulltime().replaceAll(",",".")))
         //+ ",\"email\":\"" + employee.getEmail()
         +   ",\"citizenship\":\"" + employee.getCitizenship()
         + "\",\"gnn\":\""+ employee.getGnn()
         + "\",\"company\":\"" + employee.getCompany()
         + "\",\"employeeid\":\"" + employee.getEmployeeid()
         + "\",\"customfield_12708\":\"" + employee.getStartdate()
         //+ "\",\"enddate\":\"" //+ employee.getEnddate()
    
         + "\",\"product\":\"" + employee.getProduct()
         + "\",\"customfield_12725\":\"" + employee.getInternalnumber()
        // + "\",\"employeeid\":\"" + employee.getEmployeeid()
         + "\"}}";
```

Can you please help ?

Comment: Both are Java? (Looks like JIRA).  Tried Jackson JSON Mapper?
What have you tried? 
You should provide a little more code. It is not quite obvious what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Using a web tool**

If you just want to convert it fast into a string, you can use a [Json to String converter](https://tools.knowledgewalls.com/jsontostring) on the web.

---

**Using a library**

If you however want a good solution in you applications, a way to solve this problem would be to serialize and parse using a library such as [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). This is of course, if you don't intend to create this conversion yourself.

GSON is quite easy to use and takes care of the translation for you. Se example below:

The sending application:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(employee); // Serialize (from Java class to JSON string)

// Send data (jsonStr) ...
```

The receiving application:

```
// Receive data (jsonStr) ...

Gson gson = new Gson();
Employee employee = gson.fromJson(jsonStr); // Parse (from JSON string to Java class)
```

---

GSON will by default name the fields the same as the member variable names in the Java class. If you need to change the field names in the JSON string, you can use `@SerializedName("newName")` in front of the member variables.

Example:

```
class Employee {
  ...
  @SerializedName("customfield_12721") String firstName;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use JsonConvert library to get json data.bellow are the example how to use it

```
String json = "{\"FirstName\":\"Jack\",\"LastName\":\"Tor\"}";

            var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            Console.WriteLine(data);
            Console.ReadLine();
```